# Adjust the text's vertical alignment in a FL_Widget using different fonts

Tags: c++, fonts, text-alignment, fltk

I would like to use one of the available fonts instead of the default one: the following program is inspired by the source code which can be found in `test/fonts.cxx`:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Fl_Window* G_win; 
    G_win = new Fl_Window(300,100,"The font test");

    Fl_Box* A = new Fl_Box(30,30,110,50,"The font TEST.");
    A -> box(FL_UP_BOX);

    int i = 0;
    int k = Fl::set_fonts(i ? (i>1 ? "*" : 0) : "-*");
    Fl_Box* B = new Fl_Box(145,30,110,50,"The font TEST.");
    B -> box(FL_UP_BOX);
    B -> labelfont(419);
 
    G_win->show();
    return(Fl::run());}
```

The `labelfont` command sets the widget's font corresponding to the provided `int` value (in the example, 419 corresponds to Papyrus). The problem is that the vertical alignment is different, as one may see in the figure below:

[image: Box on the left contains text in default font, Box on the right has the text with Papyrus font]

This is a problem that arises with other fonts, not only with Papyrus. I am using FLTK 1.3.5, on a macBookPro equipped with Big Sur (11.6), and I tested the above code also on a Linux Machine equipped with Ubuntu 19.04: the problem is still there even in this latter case.

Is there any way to set the vertical position as in the case of default font?

Comment: The label appears higher in your image. I tried it on similar code basically iterating over several system fonts and they appear ok on my kubuntu vm (tried also on windows). So you might be stumbling on an issue of some sort. What version of fltk are you using? Also are you building with pango support or not? You might aso try subclassing Fl_Box and overriding draw() to draw an upbox using fl_draw_box() then draw the text on top using fl_draw(label(), x, y, w, h, FL_ALIGN_CENTER).

Comment: I have tested the code on my Linux machine, equipped with Ubuntu 19.04, and I have the same problem with some fonts. I am using fltk 1.3.5 on a macBookPro equipped with Big Sur OS. Honestly, I do not know what pango support is. I thought about subclassing the Box class (and the other classes I am going to use) to overcome this issue, but I wanted to see if there is a faster solution.

Comment: The Pango library is an option FLTK can use on Linux (Unix) with X11. I don't think it's an option on macOS. It improves text rendering and is able to use replacement fonts if characters you need to render are not in the currently used font. If you're using macOS this is not for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the alignment according to font properties if you rely on the standard label drawing. This label drawing code uses (IIRC) fl_measure() to measure and position the label. This relies on font properties and such differences as seen above may occur. FLTK uses fl_measure() because it's faster than fl_text_extents().

If this is really important to you you'll have to derive your own class and override the draw() code with your own that uses fl_text_extents(), see docs:
https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.4/group__fl__attributes.html#ga14cb75a92b6cdd576f9512b38a208f8b

You can also take a look at test/unittests (build and run it), selection "rendering text" that shows the differences between fl_measure() and fl_text_extents().

Comment: Oh, I missed the `unittest`program, thanks! So, the sole way is to derive my class, and try to adjust the alignment wrt the font used.

Comment: If it's that important for you, then yes, I'm afraid that's what you need to do. Normally the default text alignment (positioned with fl_measure()) is sufficient.

Comment: I am working on this: I wrote a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70567435/13156261), related to this one. Maybe you can give some suggestions and/or hints.